# Category relationship in laravel Undefined property: stdClass::

Tags: laravel, relationship, categories, stdclass

**Hi** i'm working on a laravel training project . i'm having an issue with models and relationships when i'm trying to get the each product category name .

Here is my Product Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
   public function category()
   {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
   }
}
```

and my Category model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'categories';

   public function products()
   {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
   }
}
```

when i try to get the category name for each product like this

```
      @foreach($products as $product)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->category->name }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
```

while i run the page i get this error

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$category (View: /var/www/html/projectname/resources/views/my/products/index.blade.php)
```

can anyone tell me what's causing this error ?

**update**
here is the table structure
Products : id , name ,  category_id->unsigned()
Categories : id , name
and here is the code i use to get $products

```
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $products = DB::table('products')->where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(5);
    return view('my.products.index')->withProducts($products);
```

Comment: Show your table structures for Product and Category, perhaps problem in incorrect foreign keys

Comment: @OdinThunder i updated the post see the table structures . and get back to me

Comment: Your error message suggests that `$product` is an object/stdClass, rather than an instance of your `Product` model. Can you post the code you used to get the `$products` variable?

Comment: @SaeedKarimi I've written an answer for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using Laravel's query builder instead of Eloquent, but you're treating the result as if it was Eloquent.

When you do:

```
$products = DB::table('products')->where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(5);
```

The `$products` variable will contain a `Paginator` instance, which contains your items as instances of `stdClass`. If you want to be able to do this with Eloquent, you should try something like this:

```
$products = Product::with('category')->where('user_id', $user_id)->paginate(5);
```

This will ensure that the items returned in the paginator are instances of your `Product` Eloquent model, with the `category` relationship eager loaded (I.e. it will load the category relationship for each `Product` returned using one query, rather than 5 queries, one for every `Product`).

You should then be able to access `$product->category->name`.

Comment: Thank you , you're a genius . i can't believe i made a mistake like that .