# Relationship In laravel Undefined property: stdClass:: error

Tags: laravel

**Hi** I am new to laravel and eloquent relationships I am getting this error when i try to display the category name of the formation

> Undefined property: stdClass::$category (View: E:\khibra-platfrom\resources\views\formation\index.blade.php)

Here is my category model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    function formations()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Formation');
        }

    protected $fillable =['name','description'];
}
```

And my Formation model

```
class Formation extends Model
{
    function category()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Category',"category_id");
        }
}
```

I am trying to get category name for each formation like this

```
 @foreach($formations as $formation)

          <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$formation->id}}</th>
            <td>{{$formation->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$formation->price}}</td>
            <td>{{$formation->category->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$formation->durations}}</td>
            <td><div class="row">
          </tr>
    @endforeach
```

This is my Controller code

```
    {
        //$formations = Formation::all();
        $formations = DB::table('formations')->paginate('4');
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('formation.index',compact('categories','formations'));
    }
```

> Can any one help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Category relationship in laravel Undefined property: stdClass::](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42313991/category-relationship-in-laravel-undefined-property-stdclass)

Comment: I have tried the solution that was giving in that Question but didn't work for me ? any other suggestion

Comment: use $formations = Formation::with('category); instead of         $formations = DB::table('formations')->paginate('4');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are use `DB` facade not eloquent model

```
$formations = DB::table('formations')->paginate('4');
```

Change this to

```
Formation::with('category')->paginate(4);
```

also in model edit like this

```
class Formation extends Model 
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category',"category_id");
    }
}
```

in blade change code to

```
<td>{{$formation->category->name ?? ''}}</td>
```

For avoid error exception when one `formation` is not have `category`